# Can we view the connected component of the Picard scheme $\text{Pic}_0(X)$ as a "kernel" of the first Chern class?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

So on a curve, $\text{Pic}_0(X)$ is just the Jacobian variety, and just correspond to degree $0$ divisors. One way to extend the notion of divisors corresponding to a vector bundle is taking the first Chern class; the image of a line bundle under $c_1$ is an element of $A^1(X)$, the Chow group in codimension $1$, so we have a well-defined notion of degree, the kernel of the degree map gives a way to construct the Jacobian. Does this extend in any reasonable way to more general situations? Perhaps as the kernel of the self-intersection number of the first Chern class? The notation $\text{Pic}_0$ is quite suggestive, but I don't see it.